# debug ios app with gdb can't print NSString Object

Tags: ios, gdb

I installed gdb on a jailbreaken device (iphone5 ios7), and type the command:

```
gdb -p pid
break somewhere
info frame
```

then I want print the register $r0, $r1, $r2, but it always output is not a valid object. I don't know why. Anyone can help me?